# 7 inch tablet orientation query

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I have created an android app which works fine on phone (portrait) and on 10 inch tablet (Landscape). But problem is with 7 inch tablet.It opens in portrait mode but uses UI of tablet..so UI is looking totally distracted. I want to open app in 7 inch in landscape mode..how could it be possible through code...? Any suggestions would be appreciated,. Thanks in advance.

Manifest file declaration ---

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivityTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: what folders have you used to keep your layout files for 10inch ?

Comment: Its layout-large-land.

Comment: what layout you want to open in land in 7 inch same as 10 inch ??

Comment: Check my edited answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder in /res directory as `layout-xlarge-land` and another one as `layout-large-land` , keep the same file in both the folders and you are done.

These are recommended folders where you should put your files , this is not the complete list but it can be appended with many ,

```
layout-xlarge-land  landscape for 10 inch tablets and 10.1
layout-xlarge-port portrait for 10 inch tablets and 10.1
layout-large-land landscape for 7 inch tablets and 7.1
layout-large-port portrait for 7 inch tablets and 7.1
```

move your layout file between these folders to properly use it.

Comment: Hi, I have done as you said...Now UI is looking good in full screen...but it is displaying in portrait mode not changing its orientation to landscape.

Comment: what do you mean by its not changing ? did you create the other folders and the respective layouts with `-port` suffix ??

Answer (score 1):

I'd better leave a comment, but have not got enough reputation yet.
You should define some layout in layout-land directory, not only layout-land-large.
Looks like your tablet has non-large screen, and there is no layout for non-large landscape mode.

Comment: Ok..I will try it..and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I have done as you said...Now UI is looking good in full screen...but it is displaying in portrait mode not changing its orientation to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my answer. I changed my manifest file...like

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivityTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and dynamically changed orientation mode... like

```
if(isLargeScreen(this))
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
else
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And moved all layout files in layout-large folder instead of layout-large-land.
Thank you guys for help.